Cypress - (uncaught exception)NotSupportedError: The user agent does not support public key credentials
Normally we are able to login with self signed certificate from localhost pointing to different server.
But during cypress end to end testing, this is failing with the

(uncaught exception)NotSupportedError: The user agent does not support public key credentials

Is there a cypress setting to configure and suppress this error?
This is observed mainly in chrome, chromium and electron environment but passing for firefox browser.
cypress      : 13.3.0,
mac os sonoma: v14.4.1
chrome       : 124.x


Working reference in firefox

Is the implementation below to be changed:
export default (email, password) => {
    if (!window.PasswordCredential) {
        return Promise.resolve(false);
    }

    const cred = new PasswordCredential({
        id: email,
        password,
        name: email,
    });

    return navigator.credentials.store(cred).then(() => {
        return true;
    });
};

As per the doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PasswordCredential/PasswordCredential
I am not 100% sure if its because of PasswordCredential or browser not supporting. How can we stub this in cypress environment for chrome and other unsupported browsers?
Firefox browser is working absolutely fine, where as chrome is not. I upgraded node version from 16 to 18 and the superagent library to the latest to see if that helps, but no luck so far.

Where is the code applied? In the app or in the test setup?

@Chrome Artie - In the app

I was interested to see the Browser compatibility section of the docs you linked says the opposite to what you've described above.

Are you looking for a way to make PasswordCredential work with chrome, or a way to use self signed certificate with localhost?

Yes, manually with chrome its working which is weird. But with cypress its not working.

Can you post something we can reproduce? Perhaps link a repo.

If you have a secure site certificate, you should be able to map that site to localhost for testing purposes.
Referring to How to test an HTTPS site locally, the format in the old style cypress.json is
{
  "baseUrl": "https://my-secure-site:3000",
  "hosts": {
    "my-secure-site": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}

Note the baseUrl uses https protocol, and it's domain is mapped to  127.0.0.1 or localhost. This should stop the browser adjusting back to http protocol.
Since cypress.json is the older format, I looked for hosts option on the current documentation Configuration and could not find it.
However there is an example in the Cypress github repo here, and Gleb has a later blog using it here, so it is worth trying out.

The reason might be cypress running under HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS.
As per the documentation says:

Secure context: This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.

You may want to check how to use a valid HTTPS certificate when running cypress on different browsers.
Check this out https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/client-certificates

Chrome browser launch option  - > --use-sha1-server-handshakes 
using the above browser option might resolve your issue
sample:


Thanks for your response, but i didnt understand. How and where to configure this in playwright or cypress?

@MithunShreevatsa Update the answer. You shall pass launch option from config file (Cypress)

I tried this launch option with playwright like:
{
            name: 'Google Chrome',
            use: {
                ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
                channel: 'chrome',
                userAgent:
                    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
                bypassCSP: true,
                launchOptions: {
                    args: ['--disable-web-security', '--use-sha1-server-handshakes'],
                },
            },
        },
``` Did not work

I even tried with cypress, it didnt work there also.
 on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {                 console.log('launchOptions => ', launchOptions.args);                 launchOptions.args.push('--disable-web-security');                 launchOptions.args.push('--use-sha1-server-handshakes');             });

This option --use-sha1-server-handshakes in chrome has been deprecated
